# Facing youtube playback problem after 1 min

Tags: cobalt

I have been porting the Cobalt11 code into our embedded system and video playback get stopped after 1min. Can anyone support me to solve this issue?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question with some more valuable details. Just with the details passed we are not able to help you

Comment: The question is quite vague, there are many things that can go wrong here.  You will want to start, however, by going through the Cobalt log output to see if there are any clues there about what has happened (e.g. if there were errors or not).  Also please ensure that you are able to build and pass the nplb tests.